# Integrating Firebase with JIRA

Tags: firebase, jira, crashlytics, firebase-console

I am trying to connect JIRA With firebase console project. I have done it successfully. Now I want to know the answer for below question.

**Does Firebase reopens any closed crash on Firebase if it reoccurs and reopens the closed JIRA ticket also.**

I tested this by crashing an application and closing the ticket on Firebase, but it increased the count of the closed FIrebase crash but didn't reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

**Firebaser here**

In case of a regressed issue, a new JIRA ticket will be created (as long as you have that trigger on). The original ticket will not be updated (it will stay closed).